# Python - xpath syntax for a form (lxml.html)

Tags: python, lxml.html

```
<form method="post" name="login_form" action="/submit">
```

I'm trying to get the action attribute 
I've tried

`print fromstring(source).xpath('.//form[@action]')[0].text`, but it prints

`None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression returns the *`<form>` element*, not the attribute.

Get the attribute from the element:

```
print fromstring(source).xpath('.//form[@action]')[0].get('action')
```